# multiple oauth2 services and configurations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have an existing Spring application which is using configuration A extending 
**ResourceServerConfigureAdapter** to secure APIs against an internal oauth service A. 
I am trying to add another configuration B extending **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** which authenticates against an external oauth provider.

**The aim is to continue with B determine authentication for /api/ related endpoints while A determines overall login to the web application.**

Following is the existing code using ResourceServerConfigureAdapter:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${oauth.clientId}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${oauth.clientSecret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Bean
public RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices() {
    RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
    remoteTokenServices.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    remoteTokenServices.setClientId(clientId);
    remoteTokenServices.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    remoteTokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("srvc://myservice/api/v2/oauth/check_token");
    return remoteTokenServices;
}

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId(null);
    resources.tokenServices(remoteTokenServices());
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.anonymous()
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/secured/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
}}
```

Following is the code using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableMBeanExport(registration = RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING)
public class DemoService extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/")).and().logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoService.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter googleFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                "/login/google");
        OAuth2RestTemplate googleTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(google(), oauth2ClientContext);
        googleFilter.setRestTemplate(googleTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(googleResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                google().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(googleTemplate);
        googleFilter.setTokenServices(
                new UserInfoTokenServices(googleResource().getUserInfoUri(), google().getClientId()));
        return googleFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("google.client")
    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails google() {
        return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("google.resource")
    public ResourceServerProperties googleResource() {
        return new ResourceServerProperties();
    }

}
```

Both of them individually run fine but put together in the same project, problems start showing up. Everything compiles and runs fine but when I hit localhost:8080/ following happens -
The page loads fine but when I hit localhost:8080/login/google, it shows me a whitelabel error page like following

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Apr 06 13:22:27 IST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
Not Found
```

I try to read a bit about ResourceServerConfigureAdapter vs WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and I could only understand that there is some kind of filter-order that determines the priority of each configurer. But that hasn't helped me fix the issue. Any pointers?

Update:
There's another adapter for Swagger integration that is also part of the project.

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/docs", "/swagger-ui.html");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/docs/", "/swagger-ui.html");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/docs.json", "/v2/api-docs");
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerSpringMvcPlugin() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Spring Boot Service")
                .description("Sample project documentation")
                .contact("a@b.com")
                .version("1.0")
                .license("Apache")
                .build())
            .forCodeGeneration(true)
            .ignoredParameterTypes(Principal.class)
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .select()
            .paths(documentedPaths())
            .build();
    }

    private Predicate<String> documentedPaths() {
        return or(
            regex("/api.*"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could please the whole spring security config after updating

Answer (score 0):

`.addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);`

The `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` must after `OAuth2ClientContextFilter`, `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` will throw a `redirect exception` when the request is wrong(no `code`, etc...),

and the `OAuth2ClientContextFilter` will catch it and redirect to the `userAuthorizationUri`;

The `BasicAuthenticationFilter` is before `OAuth2ClientContextFilter` normal, , so you should change the order:

```
@Autowired
private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oAuth2ClientContextFilter;

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
    http
        .addFilterAfter(oAuth2ClientContextFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(ssoFilter(), OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class);

}
```

UPDATE:

There is another place need to be updated, if you have multi chains, you should define the request match, the default value is '/**', and the default order of `ResourceServerConfiguration` is 3, the default order of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is 100, `ResourceServerConfiguration` has high priority.

```
// only handle the request start with `/api`
http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"))
http.anonymous()
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/secured/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
```

If you put the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` before `ResourceServerConfiguration` by change the order, you should also config the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` not to handler `/api/**`

```
// skip the request start with '/api'
http.requestMatcher(new RegexRequestMatcher("^(?!/api).*$", null))
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
```

Update2:

`.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**")`

This matcher doesn't match `/login/google`, please update to `/login/**`, so it should be

`.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login/**").permitAll()`

Comment: It didn't compile but .addFilterAfter(ssoFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class) compiled but didn't work still. Do you think I need to tweak configure(HttpSecurity http) functions?

Comment: The code compiles but doesn't work. When I click on localhost:8080/login/google it still shows the whitelabel error page

Comment: there's no exception

Comment: Your suggestions sound logical and that is exactly what I was intending to do but I am still getting the white label error page, this time with (401, unauthorized access). I am sure the patterns above helped to overcome (404, not found)

Comment: still getting 401, Authentication Failed: Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed). The old code for resourceserverconfiguration had ".anonymous().and()". Even adding it back doesn't help

Comment: request url is localhost:8080/login/google. As per what I understood, you mentioned about filter order but you didnt ask me to change it. currently for web configurer, its set to -100

Comment: Yes I did update the code with `.addFilterAfter(oAuth2ClientContextFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter.class) .addFilterAfter(ssoFilter(), OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class);` and commented out the step setting filter order to -100

Comment: my bad that I didn't notice this but there's another WebMvcConfigurerAdapter for Swagger.  See my update

Comment: `Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed`, it seems you enable the anon, please disable it, `http.anonymous().disable()`

Comment: I just mentioned that the old code had it into which I am trying to add google oauth. I don't have anonymous() explicitly enabled anywhere. disabling anon explicitly converts into too many redirects error for localhost:8080

Comment: It worked finally. Using BasicAuthenticationFilter instead of OAuth2ClientContextFilter and removing .addFilterAfter(oAuth2ClientContextFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter.class) helped.

Comment: That's too weird. Could you please share a simple project to github ?

Comment: Hey chaoluo, Please give me some time before I share the project.